# A python tool like GNU's diff for shapefiles?

Tags: python, shapefile, differences

I often use the GNU [`diff`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff) tool to compare two files or even two folders for differences. I was wondering if there is a Python based tool out there that does basically the same for shapefiles?

In the first place I am interested in attribute comparison but to find also the differences in geometry would be very handy.

Maybe someone has a script at hand I could adopt from?

I do not have access to ArcGIS so it needs to be a Python standalone solution.

Comment: Have you had a look [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61473/how-to-compare-differences-in-two-shapefiles) and [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53522/how-to-find-differences-between-shapefiles)? The "Changedetector" Python script (for ArcGIS) may be what you're looking for, but I don't know if it would work as a standalone without ArcGIS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you know `shpdiff` which depends on `shapelib`? It's not Python but works similar to `diff`. You can get it from here: http://uwmike.com/maps/shapefiles/shpdiff.c

Some years ago I wrote a [blog post about it](http://www.webrian.ch/2011/07/comparison-of-shapefiles-with-shpdiff.html).

Comment: This sounds promising!